# How to pass argument from command line to bazel file

Tags: build, bazel, buildconfiguration

I have a variable declared in .bzl file example: `VERSION_NUMBER = "00"`. 
I want to override this variable from command line when i build different version of the project.
example: bazel build target `--sunbversion_number= "99"`
I want to change this variable because it is invoked in some function to create the name of the output paths.
exammple: for version "00" the outputfile will be: name_00.extension
and for version "99" the outputfile will be: name_99.extension
This is my example:
in .bzl file i declared:
`SUBVERSION_NUMBER = "99"`
and a fucntion that return a name of the file regarding to the `SUBVERSION_NUMBER`
`def get_name(SUBVERSION_NUMBER):` 
`return "test-"+SUBVERSION_NUMBER`

`OUTPUT_NAME = get_name("99")`

Then my genrule():
`genrule(name = "test",`
`srcs = [srcs]`,
`outs = [OUTPUT_NAME+".tek"],`
`cmd = "cmd to generate the file" )`
when i build this rule i get the output file  `test-99.tek`
what i want is when i run `bazel build test --//version=01` or any other suggested solution, i want to get output `test-01.tek`
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get values from the command line into a bzl file like that, but there are a few options, depending on exactly what you want to do.

One way is to use "stamping" to set the version, and then put the versioned file in a zip file with a known name, e.g. using a genrule. Build stamping is usually used for embedding a version number and other information into the output files themselves, but can be used here too. A zip file is necessary because the output file name has to be known at load time (i.e. before any configuration data from the command line is processed at analysis time).

Something like this:

```py
# out.txt is the original unversioned file
genrule(
  name = "gen_out",
  outs = ["out.txt"],
  cmd = "echo foo > $@",
)

genrule(
  name = "gen_versioned_out",
  outs = ["out_versioned.zip"],
  srcs = [":out.txt"],
  tools = ["@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper"],
  stamp = True,
  cmd = """
# bazel-out/stable-status.txt is created when stamp = True
# Value of BUILD_EMBED_LABEL key comes from --embed_label on the command line
version="$$(grep BUILD_EMBED_LABEL bazel-out/stable-status.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
# Set a reasonable default if --embed_label was not specified
if [ -z "$$version" ]; then version="0"; fi

file="$$(basename $<)"
name="$${file%%.*}"
ext="$${file#*.}"
versioned_file="$${name}_$${version}.$${ext}"

# zipper allows specifying the name of the file in the zip directly, unlike the
# regular zip tool.
# c = create
# $@ = output file from "outs"
# $< = input file from "srcs"
# $$versioned_file=$< = "put this file in to the archive with this name"
$(location @bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper) c "$@" "$$versioned_file=$<"
""",
)
```

Then:

```
$ bazel build out_versioned.zip --embed_label=99
INFO: Analyzed target //:out_versioned.zip (7 packages loaded, 19 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:out_versioned.zip up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/out_versioned.zip
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.340s, Critical Path: 0.10s
INFO: 3 processes: 1 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 3 total actions

$ unzip -l bazel-bin/out_versioned.zip
Archive:  bazel-bin/out_versioned.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        4  2010-01-01 00:00   out_99.txt
---------                     -------
        4                     1 file
```

So that results in a zip file with a known name containing the versioned file.

Another approach is to use "User-defined build settings":
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/config.html#user-defined-build-settings

Something like this:

`defs.bzl`:

```py
def _version_file_impl(ctx):
  version = ctx.attr._version[VersionProvider].version
  
  name, extension = ctx.file.file.basename.rsplit(".", 1)
  
  versioned_file = ctx.actions.declare_file(
      "%s_%s.%s" % (name, version, extension))
      
  copy_args = ctx.actions.args()
  copy_args.add_all([ctx.file.file, versioned_file])
  
  ctx.actions.run_shell(
    inputs = [ctx.file.file],
    outputs = [versioned_file],
    command = 'cp "$1" "$2"',
    arguments = [copy_args])

  return DefaultInfo(files = depset([versioned_file]))

version_file = rule(
  implementation = _version_file_impl,
  attrs = {
    "file": attr.label(mandatory = True, allow_single_file = True),
    "_version": attr.label(default = "//:version"),
  }
)

VersionProvider = provider(fields = ["version"])

def _version_flag_impl(ctx):
  return VersionProvider(version = ctx.build_setting_value)

version_flag = rule(
  implementation = _version_flag_impl,
  build_setting = config.int(flag = True),
)
```

`BUILD`:

```py
load(":defs.bzl", "version_flag", "version_file")

version_flag(
  name = "version",
  build_setting_default = 0,
)

genrule(
  name = "gen_out",
  outs = ["out.txt"],
  cmd = "echo foo > $@",
)

version_file(
  name = "versioned_out",
  file = ":out.txt",
)
```

Then:

```
$ bazel build :versioned_out --//:version=99
INFO: Analyzed target //:versioned_out (5 packages loaded, 10 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:versioned_out up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/out_99.txt
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.322s, Critical Path: 0.06s
INFO: 3 processes: 1 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 3 total actions
```

So that results in a file with the version in its name. There's no label to refer to the versioned file itself though, so `bazel build :out_99.txt` nor `srcs = [":out_99.txt"]` will work, you have to go through the `versioned_out` target.

---

Update:

Here's a version that can version multiple outputs:

`defs.bzl`:

```py
def _versioned_files_impl(ctx):
  version = ctx.attr._version[VersionProvider].version

  versioned_files = []
  for f in ctx.attr.src.files.to_list():
    name, extension = f.basename.rsplit(".", 1)

    versioned_file = ctx.actions.declare_file(
        "%s_%s.%s" % (name, version, extension))
    versioned_files.append(versioned_file)

    copy_args = ctx.actions.args()
    copy_args.add_all([f, versioned_file])

    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        inputs = [f],
        outputs = [versioned_file],
        command = 'cp "$1" "$2"',
        arguments = [copy_args])

  return DefaultInfo(files = depset(versioned_files))

versioned_files = rule(
  implementation = _versioned_files_impl,
  attrs = {
    "src": attr.label(mandatory = True),
    "_version": attr.label(default = "//:version"),
  }
)

VersionProvider = provider(fields = ["version"])

def _version_flag_impl(ctx):
  return VersionProvider(version = ctx.build_setting_value)

version_flag = rule(
  implementation = _version_flag_impl,
  build_setting = config.int(flag = True),
)
```

`BUILD`:

```py
load(":defs.bzl", "version_flag", "versioned_files")

version_flag(
  name = "version",
  build_setting_default = 0,
)

genrule(
  name = "gen_out",
  outs = ["foo.txt", "bar.txt", "baz.txt"],
  cmd = """
echo foo > $(location foo.txt)
echo bar > $(location bar.txt)
echo baz > $(location baz.txt)
""",
)

versioned_files(
  name = "versioned_files",
  src = ":gen_out",
)
```

usage:

```
$ bazel build versioned_files --//:version=123
INFO: Analyzed target //:versioned_files (5 packages loaded, 9 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:versioned_files up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/foo_123.txt
  bazel-bin/bar_123.txt
  bazel-bin/baz_123.txt
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.491s, Critical Path: 0.06s
INFO: 5 processes: 1 internal, 4 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
```

---

Update:

An example of putting the version in a cc target's define:

`BUILD`:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = ["main.cc"],
  defines = ["VERSION=\\\"$(VERSION)\\\""],
)
```

`main.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef VERSION
#define VERSION "0.0.0"
#endif

int main() {
    std::cout << "version: " << VERSION << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

build and run:

```
$ bazel run main --define=VERSION=1.2.3
INFO: Analyzed target //:main (15 packages loaded, 52 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/main
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.524s, Critical Path: 0.26s
INFO: 6 processes: 4 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions
version: 1.2.3
```

Combining the above methods, you would have to specify both `--//:version=1.2.3` and `--define=VERSION=1.2.3` on the command line. There's a way to have only `--//:version`, but it would require another Starlark rule like `versioned_files` which either

1. generates a file with the version in it that goes in the `data` attribute and the program reads at runtime, or
2. a Starlark rule which generates a C++ file with the version in it, which then gets put in the sources of a `cc_library`, which the rest of your program can depend on and use at compile time.

These approaches will probably require refactoring your program.

Comment: Thanks foy your solution, it worksbut in my case i have a function that retrun the name:example:  
get_outs_name(subversion_number,static_number):  
       return static_number+"-"+subversion_number  

name = get_outs_name(subversion_number=99, static_number=01)  

and then in genrule:  
'genrule(
  name = "gen_out",
  outs = [name+".txt"],
  cmd = "echo foo > $@",
)  '
how could i pass the subversion_from a flag to the function get_out_name()?

Comment: My suggestion is to use a fixed / constant file name throughout the build, and then as the last step, use the suggestions in the answer above to rename the final artifact using the version number. Unfortunately without seeing the rest of the context it's hard to give more specific advice. If you can provide a minimal but complete example of the problem you're trying to solve in your question, it might be possible to find a better solution.

Comment: i've updated my question to be more clear, i hope this will helps to find a solution.
Thanks

Comment: The 2nd approach in the answer above could be what you're looking for (use "User-defined build settings"). Basically remove `SUBVERSION_NUMBER`, `get_name`, and `OUTPUT_NAME`, change your genrule to just `outs = ["test.tek"]`, then use the `version_file` rule and the rest to rename the `test.tek` output to have the version name in it.

Comment: Thanks, it works , i just have one question, what if i my genrule generate multiple files with different extensions?

Comment: I updated the answer with a version that can version multiple files from a genrule

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, but what if i want to use this version number declared in the command line in another rule something like this:  
`cc_library(name="any",  
                  srcs=["some_sources"],  
                  defines = "VARIABLE=SUBVERSION_NUMBER"  
)`
SUBVERSION_NUMBER should be the value executed from command line,   `
**bazel build target --//:version=123**  

`cc_library(name="any",  
                  srcs=["some_sources"],  
                  defines = "VARIABLE=123"  
)`
Thanks

Comment: I added an example of how to use `--define` to do this. This would require both `--//:version=1.2.3` and `--define=VERSION=1.2.3` to be specified on the command line, but there are ways around that, but the alternatives would probably require refactoring your program.